# After Patching Data, NewForm Displays Last Submitted Data when creating new Record?

Tags: edit-form, newform, patching

I have created a record by using patch statement using form on submit, and when I go for creating new record (+), the form shows last submitted data filled in?

why it's happening like that, although I have set NewForm(form1); on (+) button.

any Help?

[image: New Button for Record]

[image: Form at First]

[image: Selected Leave Type From Dropdown Shows Fields]

[image: Submit Button, Patches Record to SP List]

Comment: Can you please add the screenshots of the screen where the advanced properties are visible?
Also, check what is set into the Default advance properties of the form fields

Comment: I have updated my Post, can you please go thorugh it, I have uploaded them step by step @LittSpector

Answer (score 1):

Once you submit your form you need to reset it using `ResetForm(Form1)` that will reset all the fields to blank again. If you have used patch you will have to individually reset them as `Reset(TextInput1)`

Comment: Hello, Mr @Akshay, I have to include some more code of if statement and then the patch code with some different fields do I have to reset them all and then navigate to Gallery screen?

Comment: yes, whenever you are navigating you can clear the fields, when you are back to screen you can re-populate fields if necessary